# Upload preview image using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying upload file and immediately preview there uploaded image. I have there 2 file upload one is for profile and second one is logo. When I upload profile image preview in logo section instead of profile section. Below, I given code, please help me.
Profile Upload code:

```
<input type="file" name="profile_img" id="imageUpload" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" />
<div id="imagePreview" style="background-image: url(images/profile.jpg);">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $('#imagePreview').css('background-image', 'url('+e.target.result +')');
                $('#imagePreview').hide();
                $('#imagePreview').fadeIn(650);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    $("#imageUpload").change(function() {
        readURL(this);
    });         
</script>
```

Logo Upload code:

```
<input type="file" name="logo_img" id="logoUpload" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" />
<div id="logoPreview" style="background-image: url(images/profile.jpg);">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $('#logoPreview').css('background-image', 'url('+e.target.result +')');
                $('#logoPreview').hide();
                $('#logoPreview').fadeIn(650);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    $("#logoUpload").change(function() {
        readURL(this);
    });         
</script>
```

Comment: Is all that code in the same file?

Comment: Yes, all code in same file.

Comment: You're defining the the function `readURL()` twice.

Comment: What can i do, Please help me.

Comment: I've posted an answer with a couple of ways to solve it

Comment: As Magnus says, you are defining the function twice. You should add a parameter to the readURL function readURL(input, selector) and use the selector to set preview the image

Comment: If the answer worked for you, feel free to accept it so other people here knows it has been resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define multiple functions with the same name, only the last defined function will be used.

You can either just call them different things, example: `readProfileURL()` and `readLogoURL()`.

However, since your functions are so similar, a better approach would be to only have one function where you pass the differences:

```
function readURL(input, previewId) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $(previewId).css('background-image', 'url('+e.target.result +')');
            $(previewId).hide();
            $(previewId).fadeIn(650);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Now you can call it with:

```
$("#imageUpload").change(function() {
    readURL(this, '#imagePreview');
});
```

and

```
$("#logoUpload").change(function() {
    readURL(this, '#logoPreview');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, It's Work. Thank You So Much.

Comment: This is a well-written answer, should anyone see my comment ;-) That's how things are/should be done.